# Get events of group using vk api

Tags: php, vk

I want to get list of events by group id using VK api.

I searching for answer in [VK api documentation](https://vk.com/dev/).

There is api to get all user's events but can't find way to see all events organized by group.

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible. In VK no method for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

VK has callback api for that. You need to configure your callback-api url in your settings of group and get token. 
Also read [documentations](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api)

Comment: can you provide more details about accessing list of events from callback?